# c# finding characters between brackets

Tags: c#, string, character, brackets

I can't get it to work, 
I need to get a character ex : i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey

i would like to take the L, B and H out of this string and show them in a console writeline
without using regex 
I though about finding the position of [ with an indexof and add + 1 to get the letter and then replace the [ with something else ex: [ into & 
so i could do a foreach bracket in that string... but i don't think it'll work o.O

```
Console.WriteLine("Characters are : ");
foreach(Brackets in sentence)..
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use regex?

Comment: @Lloyd Because it can be done without a regex with relative ease.

Answer (score 6):

```
string str = " i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";
string[] array = str.Split('[');
foreach (var item in array)
{
    if(item.Contains(']'))
        Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
}
```

and you will get:

```
L
B
H
```

This would work as long as you don't have unpaired square brackets and there is a character between those square brackets.

Comment: what if I used a "," to split my string?...for example if I have my str="i ,L,ove ,B,asketball and ,H,ockey" and now I want to retrieve L B H what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the split:

```
string str = " i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == '[')
        Console.WriteLine(str[1 + i++]);
}
```

Comment: If you use the pre-increment rather than the post-increment in the body of your loop it'll make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to get the values between the brakets:

```
string input = "I [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";
var regex = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    var letter = Regex.Replace(match.ToString(), @"\[|\]", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
string s = "i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";
var chars = s.Where((c, i) => i > 0            && s[i - 1] == '[' && 
                              i < s.Length - 1 && s[i + 1] == ']');
```

Equivalently:

```
var chars = Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - 2)
                      .Where(i => s[i - 1] == '[' && s[i + 1] == ']')
                      .Select(i => s[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

```
string str = " i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"\[(.*?)\]");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//iterate over all matches
do
{
 sb.Append(match);
 match = match.NextMatch();
}while(match.Success); //condition
//note: Dump() only works in linqpad. Use Console.WriteLine() instead
sb.Dump();
//without brackets:
sb.ToString().Split(new []{'[',']'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with lengthy code but it works with all the cases

Try This:

```
   static  void Main()
    {
        string line =  "i [L]ove [B]asketball and [H]ockey";
        int count = 0;
        char temp=' ';
        string str="";
        foreach (char ch in line)
        {
            if (ch == '[')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if (count ==1)
            {
                count++;
                temp=ch;
            }
            else if(count==2 && ch==']')
            {
                str+=temp;
                count=0;
            }              
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```